# Android: How to force onStartCommand() being called before onBind()?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to create a sticky service that is bindable to (I need to run potentially asynchronic operations in the background on some data that the service holds). To do this, I need to be sure that onBind always runs after onStartCommand. Is there any way to guarantee this?

Comment: "I need to run potentially asynchronic operations in the background on some data that the service holds" -- that does not require binding.

Comment: Two years later, but... My answer might help. Try the IntentService approach.

Answer (score 9):

From your requirements, you probably don't need to bind to your `Service`. Then using an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) would suffice, as this service will stop itself after its work is done.

Taken from the docs:

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.

An example of an `IntentService`:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            // Do some work here, get Intent extras if any, etc.
            // ...
            // Once this method ends, the IntentService will stop itself.
        }
    }   
}
```

More info on how to create an `IntentService` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

That can handle your asynchronous operations. And if you need any feedback, which will "break" the async part of the requirement, you could use a [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or as you said, you could bind to this [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Service.html). And then again, it depends on what you're trying to do.

From the docs, you have two types of services.

**Started**

> A service is "started" when an application component (such as an
>   activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service
>   can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that
>   started it is destroyed. Usually, a started service performs a single
>   operation and does not return a result to the caller. For example, it
>   might download or upload a file over the network. When the operation
>   is done, the service should stop itself.

**Bound**

> A service is "bound" when an application component binds to it by
>   calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server
>   interface that allows components to interact with the service, send
>   requests, get results, and even do so across processes with
>   interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as
>   another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can
>   bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service
>   is destroyed.

**Reminder:** You can start a `Service` through `startService()` to make it run "indefinitely" and bind to it by calling `onBind()` later.

```
Intent it = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(it); // Start the service.
bindService(it, this, 0); // Bind to it.
```

If you want to simply run this service for as long as your `Activity` is running, you could just call `onBind()`.

```
Intent it = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
bindService(it, this, 0); // This will create the service and bind to it.
```

More info on "default" `Service`, how to use it and implement it can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Just choose what works best for your use case, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, you're not supposed to call both startService() and bindService(). If you want to bind to a service, call bindService(). When the service is connected, your implementation of ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() is called, giving you an IBinder to the Service. Typically, a bound service is used as the server part of an internal client-server interface. You bind to the service, get back an IBinder that gives you a handle to the Service object itself, and then use the Service handle to pass data or call methods in the Service.

Bound services are almost always used to connect between processes (IPC).

Comment: This is false.  Reread this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html . Specifically this paragraph: Although this documentation generally discusses these two types of services separately, your service can work both ways—it can be started (to run indefinitely) and also allow binding. It's simply a matter of whether you implement a couple callback methods: onStartCommand() to allow components to start it and onBind() to allow binding.  ALSO, you can't use the service object for IPC, you have to either use a Messenger or AIDL.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer ?? This is bluntly wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

A service can essentially take two forms:

> **Started**
>       A service is "started" when an application component (such as an activity) starts it by calling startService().  
> **Bound**
>       A service is "bound" when an application component binds to it by calling bindService(). [..] A bound service runs only as long as
>   another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can
>   bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service
>   is destroyed.

To make sure that `onStartCommand()` is always executed before `onBind()`, keep sending a new intent to the service anytime you want to bind to it. This is because any [new intent to the service will trigger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) `onStartCommand()`, then a call to `bindService()` will execute the `onBind()`.

Comment: The problem is, when I call `startService()` and then almost immediately `bindService()`, Android sometimes schedules `onBind()` before `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: The third form of service is a hybrid. Note that oBind() can itself call startService(self)